definite integration with variable limits
$$\int_{-\phi}^\phi\frac{\sqrt{1 + e^{2 i \theta} - 2 e^{i \theta}\cos(\phi)}}{  1 + \alpha e^{i \theta}}d\theta$$
Assuming $\pi > \phi> 0, 1 > \alpha > 0$
I am trying to solve this integral analytically; I think I can solve this integration by using residue(it is not possible because $\pi > \phi> 0$ and closed couture are not formed )
Do you have any idea how to solve this Integration?
The aim of this integration is to find out the value of $\phi$
$$\int_{-\phi}^\phi\frac{\sqrt{1 + e^{2 i \theta} - 2 e^{i \theta}\cos(\phi)}}{  1 + \alpha e^{i \theta}}d\theta  = 1$$

Did you at least try $e^{i\theta}=x$ ? The antiderivative is not so hard.

@ClaudeLeibovici I didn't learn complex differentiation yet, but is $dx=ie^{i\theta} d\theta$ for the substitution you gave? So we treat $i$ as a constant?

@Gwen Yes, that's correct.


Here is an approach that avoids advanced concepts like contour integration and instead uses basic (but tedious!) complex algebra to reduce the problem to an integral in purely real variables.

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:(0,1)\times(0,\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ via the definite integral
$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a,\beta\right)}:=\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{i\theta}},$$
where here $\sqrt{z}$ denotes the principal square root of a complex number $z$. For a complex number $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with modulus $|z|=r\ge0$ and principal argument $\arg{\left(z\right)}=\varphi\in(-\pi,\pi]$, the principal square root is defined as
$$\sqrt{z}:=\sqrt{r}e^{i\varphi/2}.$$
It can be shown that the principal square root can be expressed algebraically as
$$\sqrt{x+iy}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}+x}{2}}+i\left[2H{\left(y\right)}-1\right]\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}-x}{2}};~~~\small{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}},$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside step function.

Suppose $0<a<1\land0<\beta<\pi$. Using the even symmetry of the integral, we can show that
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a,\beta\right)}
&=\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{i\theta}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{i\theta}}+\int_{-\beta}^{0}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{i\theta}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{i\theta}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\sqrt{e^{-2i\theta}-2e^{-i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{-i\theta}};~~~\small{\left[\theta\mapsto-\theta\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\left[\frac{\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{i\theta}}+\frac{\sqrt{e^{-2i\theta}-2e^{-i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{-i\theta}}\right]\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\Re{\left[\frac{\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{i\theta}}\right]}.\\
\end{align}$$
It can be shown that for two complex numbers $z_{1}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $z_{2}\in\mathbb{C}$ with $z_{2}\neq0$, the real part of their ratio can be expressed as
$$\Re{\left[\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}}\right]}=\frac{\Re{\left[z_{1}\right]}\,\Re{\left[z_{2}\right]}+\Im{\left[z_{1}\right]}\,\Im{\left[z_{2}\right]}}{\left|z_{2}\right|^{2}}.$$
Then, it is possible to reduce $\mathcal{I}$ to an elementary integral of a real algebraic function:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a,\beta\right)}
&=2\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\Re{\left[\frac{\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}}{1+ae^{i\theta}}\right]}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{\Re{\left[\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}\right]}\,\Re{\left[1+ae^{i\theta}\right]}+\Im{\left[\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}\right]}\,\Im{\left[1+ae^{i\theta}\right]}}{\left|1+ae^{i\theta}\right|^{2}}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\left[1+a\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right]\Re{\left[\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}\right]}+a\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\,\Im{\left[\sqrt{e^{2i\theta}-2e^{i\theta}\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}\right]}}{a^{2}+2a\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{1}{a^{2}+2a\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+1}\\
&~~~~~\times\bigg{[}\left[1+a\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right]\sqrt{\left[\cos{\left(\theta\right)}-\cos{\left(\beta\right)}\right]\left[1+\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~+a\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\sqrt{\left[\cos{\left(\theta\right)}-\cos{\left(\beta\right)}\right]\left[1-\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right]}\bigg{]}\\
&=2\int_{1}^{\cos{\left(\beta\right)}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{a^{2}+2ax+1}\\
&~~~~~\times\bigg{[}\left(1+ax\right)\sqrt{\left[x-\cos{\left(\beta\right)}\right]\left(1+x\right)}\\
&~~~~~+a\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{\left[x-\cos{\left(\beta\right)}\right]\left(1-x\right)}\bigg{]};~~~\small{\left[\theta=\arccos{\left(x\right)}\right]}\\
&=2\int_{b}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(a^{2}+2ax+1\right)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~\times\bigg{[}\left(1+ax\right)\sqrt{\left(x-b\right)\left(1+x\right)}+a\left(1-x\right)\sqrt{\left(x-b\right)\left(1+x\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=2\int_{b}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(1+a\right)\sqrt{\left(x-b\right)\left(1+x\right)}}{\left(a^{2}+2ax+1\right)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=2\left(1+a\right)\int_{b}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{x-b}}{\left(2ax+a^{2}+1\right)\sqrt{1-x}}\\
&=\frac{1+a}{a}\int_{b}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{x-b}}{\left(x+\frac{a^{2}+1}{2a}\right)\sqrt{1-x}},\\
\end{align}$$
where in the last line above we've set $b:=\cos{\left(\beta\right)}\in(-1,1)$.

Now, given $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $a>b>c$, we find
$$\begin{align}
\int_{b}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{x-b}}{\left(x-c\right)\sqrt{a-x}}
&=\int_{b}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x-c}\sqrt{\frac{x-b}{a-x}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(a-b\right)}{\left(y+1\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\left(\frac{ay+b}{y+1}\right)-c};~~~\small{\left[\frac{x-b}{a-x}=y\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(a-b\right)}{\left(y+1\right)}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\left(ay+b\right)-c\left(y+1\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(a-b\right)\sqrt{y}}{\left[\left(a-c\right)y+\left(b-c\right)\right]\left(y+1\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\left(a-b\right)t^{2}}{\left[\left(a-c\right)t^{2}+\left(b-c\right)\right]\left(t^{2}+1\right)};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{y}=t\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\left(\frac{a-b}{a-c}\right)t^{2}}{\left[t^{2}+\left(\frac{b-c}{a-c}\right)\right]\left(t^{2}+1\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\left(1-p^{2}\right)t^{2}}{\left(t^{2}+p^{2}\right)\left(t^{2}+1\right)};~~~\small{\left[p:=\sqrt{\frac{b-c}{a-c}}\in(0,1)\right]}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[\frac{1}{t^{2}+1}-\frac{p^{2}}{t^{2}+p^{2}}\right]\\
&=2\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t^{2}+1}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{p^{2}}{t^{2}+p^{2}}\right]\\
&=2\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t^{2}+1}-p\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{u^{2}+1}\right];~~~\small{\left[t=pu\right]}\\
&=2\left(1-p\right)\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t^{2}+1}\\
&=\pi\left(1-p\right)\\
&=\pi\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{b-c}{a-c}}\right).\\
\end{align}$$
It follows that
$$\int_{b}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{x-b}}{\left(x+\frac{a^{2}+1}{2a}\right)\sqrt{1-x}}=\pi\left[1-\sqrt{\frac{b+\left(\frac{a^{2}+1}{2a}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{a^{2}+1}{2a}\right)}}\right];~~~\small{0<a\land-1<b<1}.$$

Hence, for $0<a<1\land0<\beta<\pi$ with $b:=\cos{\left(\beta\right)}$, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a,\beta\right)}
&=\frac{1+a}{a}\int_{b}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{x-b}}{\left(x+\frac{a^{2}+1}{2a}\right)\sqrt{1-x}}\\
&=\left(\frac{1+a}{a}\right)\pi\left[1-\sqrt{\frac{b+\left(\frac{a^{2}+1}{2a}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{a^{2}+1}{2a}\right)}}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{a}\left[\left(a+1\right)-\left(a+1\right)\sqrt{\frac{a^{2}+2ab+1}{\left(a+1\right)^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi\left[a+1-\sqrt{a^{2}+2ab+1}\right]}{a}\\
&=\frac{\pi\left[a+1-\sqrt{a^{2}+2a\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+1}\right]}{a}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

